# REST document url

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, url

I'm using rest to develop an add-in, the URL looks like this:

```
url: appurl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('" + ListName + "')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,Modified,CheckoutUserId,AuthorId,OData__UIVersionString&@target='" + hosturl + "'"
```

I'm missing one thing, the documents relative URL. How can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileRef` should give you the document's relative URL. `$select` should look like

```
$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,Modified,CheckoutUserId,AuthorId,OData__UIVersionString
```

## FileRef vs FileLeafRef

- `FileRef` is for document's relative URL
- `FileLeafRef` is for document's name

## Modified Code

```
url: appurl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('" + ListName + "')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,Modified,CheckoutUserId,AuthorId,OData__UIVersionString&@target='" + hosturl + "'"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I was trying EncodedAbsUrl but that was not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: BTW, EncodedAbsUrl is only works if you need picture URKL from Picture Library. :)